# Angular 2 automatic routing after some seconds

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

how can i navigate from  app component html to another component html in 2000 milliseconds without clicking anything .I have tried using router.navigate method but it's not working .It is staying at the app component html only.
App component.ts

```
   import { Component ,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule,Router} from '@angular/router';
import { SecondComponent } from './second/second.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],

})
export class AppComponent {

constructor(private router: Router){}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
 setTimeout(() => {
    this.router.navigate(["/second"]);
 }, 2000);
}
    }
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SecondComponent } from './second/second.component';
import {RouterModule,Router,Routes} from '@angular/router'
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'second', component: SecondComponent },

];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SecondComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
    ],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

App component.html :

```
<div class="my-container">
   <h3 id ="h31">Digit</h3>
</div>


 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

secondpage component.html : i want to redirect to this page after 2 seconds

```
<div class="my-container">

<h3>Insurance made simple</h3>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Lets get started</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Please provide the code where you have tried it

Comment: app component.ts

Comment: Is the target component the same (with added params or something) or different?

Comment: this is the code

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you want to do is, start a timer using `setTimout` and call a function on its completion:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.router.navigate(["foo"]);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: import { Component ,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule,Router} from '@angular/router';
import { SecondComponent } from './second/second.component';





@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
 
})
export class AppComponent {
  
constructor(private router: Router){}
  
  ngOnInit() {


        setTimeout(() => {
    this.router.navigate(["second"]);
}, 2000);

    
   
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Please use the

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.router.navigate(["foo"]);
}, 2000);
```

in the life-cycle hook `ngAfterViewInit()` like this in the component,

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
 setTimeout(() => {
    this.router.navigate(["foo"]);
 }, 2000);
}
```

See if that fixed your issue.

**UPDATE**

Modify your `AppComponent` to implement the `AfterViewInit` lifeCycle hook/interface,

```
import { AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
```

**UPDATE_2:**

Ideally, if you don't want to show the contents of the current `app.component.html` in your routed `SecondComponent`, then you should make another component (say `DefaultComponent`) for it, move the rest of the template other than `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` from `app.component.html` to the DefaultComponent's template and make that as the default route to go to by setting the new path (for DefaultComponent) and a default path (to the new path) as:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
 { path: '', redirectTo: '/default', pathMatch: 'full' },
 { path: 'default', component: DefaultComponent },
 { path: 'second', component: SecondComponent },
];
```

> app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet> <!-- Move the rest of the html present here to the DefaultComponent -->
```

Comment: giving me error showing cannot find name setTimeOut

Comment: @NikhilKumar - use `setTimeout` instead of `setTimeOut`

Comment: main.bundle.js:46400 Router Event: NavigationStart
main.bundle.js:46401 NavigationStart(id: 1, url: '/')
main.bundle.js:46402 NavigationStart
main.bundle.js:782 Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
main.bundle.js:46400 Router Event: NavigationError
main.bundle.js:46401 NavigationError(id: 1, url: '/', error: Error: Cannot match any routes: '')
main.bundle.js:46402 NavigationError
main.bundle.js:41250 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: ''

Comment: are you giving a valid route to route to? Can you show your route definitions and the way you call it in the component for navigating to it?

Comment: I am not able to edit my question and can't send the code in comments .

Comment: can you post your current url and the url you wanna route to in the comments section?

Comment: current url is http://localhost:4200 and i want to route to http://localhost:4200/second. The url is changing after 2 seconds but not the content and it is showing error in console showing Error: Cannot match any routes: ''

Comment: where have you defined your `path` for this route, for routing? Likely in an `AppModule` or an `AppRoutingModule`. Could you show that as well (where you use `RouterModule.forRoot()`)?

Comment: i have done that in appmodule only .If u see the app .module.ts code you will find const app routes : Routes {path : second ,component : secondComponent } and in the imports i am using RouterModule.forRoot and passing that app routes array

Comment: If it is like this as mentioned `const app routes : Routes {path : second ,component : secondComponent }` change it to this: `const app routes : Routes  = { path : 'second', component : secondComponent  }`. Also, are you sure your component name here starts with a 'lowercase', secondComponent or SecondComponent ?

Comment: sorry, just looked at your updated question. Seeing it now

Comment: it is now showing the content of the second page but it still contains the app component html content too and after that only it is showing me the second page content .I want to show only the second page content after routing.How to achieve that?

Comment: Updated again: see UPDATE_2

Comment: I have to use a common header but it should show from second page and should be constant for all the other pages ,but it should not show on the app component html.  How to achieve that?

Comment: What is your `app.component.html` supposed to show ? Or is it ever gonna be showed at all?